# How to find the QtQuick UI File template in the Qt Creator?

Tags: qt

I cannot find the QtQuick UI File template on the Qt Creator templates screen. How can I solve this problem? I have Qt 6.3.1

Answer (score 0):

They just changed the place of it from QtCreator to QtDesign Studio. If you are using Linux you can find it in

> "Qt installed Folder"/Tools/QtDesignStudio/bin/qtdesignstudio

It might be like the picture.
[image: QtQuick UI File]